# Approaches to adding node attribute data to graph of 100+ nodes

Tags: python, networkx

I have created a graph from a `shapefile`. I would like to

1. import the length of edges as attributes of the edges
2. add weights to the nodes

This is for a **shortest path problem**. Adding weight on the nodes is intended to influence the search paths.

I am using `networkx`. Is there a better library for this problem?

Thanks. x

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `nx.set_edge_attributes(x, data[2:])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`networkx` is arguably the most widely used python library for graphs.

To add node attributes, use the `set_node_attributes` function. Likewise for edge attributes, there's a `set_edge_attributes` function.

For example, to add node weights and edge lengths:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 2}, 'weight') # add node weights
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, {('A','B'): 2, ('B','C'): 10}, 'length') # add edge lengths
```

`networkx` has a host of shortest-path algorithms for different types of graphs. The documentation is [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html).

Comment: Thanks Adarsh. I went on to create a csv file of over 100 node attributes. Is there an approach I can use to use a dictionary/list from a csv file? If so how do I read, line by line, `set_node_attributes` for a bunch of nodes?